# How to make a multidimensional array in Natural?

Tags: mainframe, adabas-natural

Does the redefine below in the code make #JF-ARRAY a single dimensional array in Natural. I want to make this a 5 dimensional array but I am not certain as if that would be something like.

```
   myVariable (A5/7500)
```

or if there is another format that would allow me to do this.

```
LOCAL                     
1 #JETFORMS-DATA (A7500)  
1 REDEFINE #JETFORMS-DATA 
  2 #JF-ARRAY (A1/7500)
```

**Question: How to make a array in Natural?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit (not much) of searching reveals this: http://documentation.softwareag.com/natural/nat638vms/pg/pg_defi_array.htm

From the article:

To define a one-dimensional array

After the format and length, specify a slash followed by a so-called "index notation", that is, the number of occurrences of the array.

For example, the following one-dimensional array has three occurrences, each occurrence being of format/length A10:

```
DEFINE DATA LOCAL 
1 #ARRAY (A10/1:3) 
END-DEFINE 
...
```

Specify an index notation for both dimensions:

```
DEFINE DATA LOCAL 
1 #ARRAY (A10/1:3,1:4) 
END-DEFINE 
...
```

A two-dimensional array can be visualized as a table. The array defined in the example above would be a table that consists of 3 "rows" and 4 "columns":

Answer (score 0):

Natural can only handle up to 3 Array Dimensions.

You could, for example, redefine your data in 3D like this:

```
LOCAL 1     #JETFORMS-DATA (A7500)  
      1                                   REDEFINE  #JETFORMS-DATA 
       2    #JF-ARRAY      (A25/3,10,10)
```